# how to read a simple strings text file in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, read-text

I have a list of strings saved in text file without header, and wanted to open in pyspark notebook in databricks and print all lines.

```
abcdef 
vcdfgrs 
vcvdfrs 
vfdedsew 
kgsldkflfdlfd

text = sc.textFile("path.../filename.txt)
print(text.collect())
```

this code is not printing lines. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes

```
#define a function which takes line and print
def f(line):
    print(line)

#building the text file via list
my_list = [['my text line-1'],['line-2 text2 my2'],['some junk line-3']]

#create RDD via list (you have it via 
txt_file = sc.parallelize(my_list)

#use for each to call the function and print will work
txt_file.foreach(f)

#if you want each word via line, use flatmap
```

[image]